# how to copy received data from string into 1d char array c# forms

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

So im just learning C# and trying to use arrays, im getting input from user via a forms app and wish to copy it to an array called prevPos, in the format below

receiving data (string):

```
string1: "hello"
string2: "123"
```

```
       //counting how many lines and using that to determine position associated with each 
       recieved 
      char[] prevPos;
      prevPos = textBox_ReceievedData.Text.ToCharArray();

      //count how many lines of receieved data in textbox
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox_ReceievedData.Lines.Length; i++)
        {

            System.Console.WriteLine("charArray "  +prevPos[i]);
        }
```

right now if i wish to call it, i would get this, i do not want this fomat:

```
        prevPos[1]=h
        prevPos[2]=e 
        prevPos[3]=l
       etc.
```

I want this output:

```
prevPos[1]=hello
prevPos[2]=123
```

Comment: why are you not using String [] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please replace with the below and try

```
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox_ReceievedData.Lines.Length; i++)
        {

            System.Console.WriteLine("Each Line "  +textBox_ReceievedData.Lines[i]);
        }
```

Comment: while that gets it in the right format, i wish to store it into the array prevPos, how would i do that?

Comment: **textBox_ReceievedData.Lines** is the array, so prevPos = textBox_ReceievedData.Lines should do

Answer (score 0):

```
prevPos = textBox_ReceievedData.Text.Split('\n');
```

This will give you an array of all text separated by the new line character `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the output you desire, then a **string array** (not a char array) is what you want.  The Lines() property already gives you that, though:

```
string[] prevPos = textBox_ReceievedData.Lines;
for(int i=0; i< prevPos.Length; i++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(prevPos[i]);
}
```

Comment: your way and arun works but for your method, if initialize i as 1 for both methods and go [i-1] i will get the same string everythime but if i go [i-1] with @aruns method i get the previous, which i am abit confused about because your method looks very similar

Comment: would love to but unfortunately, i can't because its part  of my assignment and its worth 50%